# Define specific object payload for different enums

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this code -- I know it's wrong.

```
 enum SocketClient {
  PLAYER_LOGIN = "player:login",
  PLAYER_LOGOUT = "player:logout",
}

enum SocketClientPayload {
  PLAYER_LOGIN = { user: string; pass: string};
  PLAYER_LOGOUT  =  { uuid: string;}
} 


 type wsMessage = {
  event: typeof SocketClient;
  payload: SocketClientPayload[SocketClient];
};
```

I want the `payload` at the bottom to be tied to the whatever I specify for the incoming `SocketEvent` so that every `SocketEvent`'s `payload` is typed. Is there a way to do dynamic form types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for this. For example:

```
 enum SocketClient {
  PLAYER_LOGIN = "player:login",
  PLAYER_LOGOUT = "player:logout",
}

type SocketClientPayload = {
  [SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGIN]: { user: string; pass: string; };
  [SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGOUT]: { uuid: string; };
};

type wsMessage<T extends SocketClient> = {
  event: T;
  payload: SocketClientPayload[T];
};

let test: wsMessage<SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGOUT> = {
    event: SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGOUT,
    payload: { uuid: 'test' }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwdgrgtsDKD2BjA1iALgYQDYEtxuAG8BYAKGGAAUAZAQQE0BRAJQH1qB5AcQEkA5YAF5gAIgAOWAIYBPEACcAXFngBzHGBEAaMhRoMW7bhwCqAFSGiJM+UtXwIaLWQC+ZMmmliQcJKky58ShllSQATCxJyYABtBBR0bDwwNAA6PSY2Tl4+AF0FImAIAGcbYCK0OXUVAG5gMUkiovzyyrAa4GdqnRi4v0T8NLoMwy4TUzyCiAgcUOaKqtrOly7Sd09vAHcigFkQRskVEAAecxAADzRwUKKfeP8ktAA+CO6QADd8fNMVinrpENmtz6AWSQX+8DC0XGKyWq1IWHQwEu5XyW12+0OR16CRBqXSBiyY2ewkiFAo70+QJxD0G+kyRjM2iiv2CEMBhEK00BAHJkWhuR1lmQgA)

By making your `wsMessage` type generic, you can have it figure out which payload type to use based on which member of your `SocketClient` enum was used to instantiate it.

Note that TypeScript doesn't infer generic types when used like this, which is why I've had to specify that the `test` variable I've created is of type `SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGOUT` even though that could theoretically be determined based on the value of the `event` property. But TypeScript can infer this when used in a generic function. For example:

```
function processPayload<T extends SocketClient>(message: wsMessage<T>) {
    // Do something
}

// TypeScript can see the argument is of type `wsMessage<SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGIN>` based on its `event` property, and it infers the generic type of the function from that.
processPayload(
    {
        event: SocketClient.PLAYER_LOGIN,
        payload: { user: 'test', pass: 'test' },
    },
);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-m6sEM-lCIUSopgAByS7lNuaOuNfIdvZoNsdav55zV1krIA)

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you. I understand so much. Seems like the difference in both solutions is that you're instantiating the first one with a generic in `wsMessage` whereas in the function you are providing the first argument with `SocketClient` and from there it infers the payload. Do I have that?

Comment: Yeah that's it. Though, come to think of it, I don't actually need that first argument in the function version. It can infer it from the `event` property in the message argument. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.